# Htaccess 301 Redirect of complex search page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem with 301 redirecting the following url:

> > domain.com/browse.php?catName=**test**&cityName=**cityhere**&keywork=&category=0&city=0&price=0&type=0

To this:

> > domain.com/ads-**test**-in-**cityhere**/?keywork=&category=0&city=0&price=0&type=0

The url can change by adding more variables from the search fields, so it can be like this:

> > domain.com/browse.php?catName=**test**&cityName=**cityhere**&keywork=&category=0&city=0&price=0&type=0&anothervar=0&var=9 etc.

It doesn't have a fixed number of variables. Basically i need to redirect based on **catName** and **cityName** (and also remove this 2 vars from last part of url), the rest should stay intact and show after **/?**

The url is created by the user when submitting a search form.

Is it possible? If so, how can i achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root try adding this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^catName=([^&]+)&cityName=([^&]+)&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^browse.php$ /ads-%1-in-%2/?%3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It's working, thank you very much! I still have a small question, the code is redirecting ok but i dont see browse.php, i see index.php (wich is default for 404 redirect). Could you please help me with that? Thank you again.

Comment: @doubleb I don't know what you mean by not seeing `browse.php`.

Comment: The url is correctly displayed in address bar but it doesn't display the browse.php page, besides the redirect code should I add anything else?

Comment: @doubleb I have no idea how you have your site setup, your server is now getting the request `/ads-test-in-cityhere/?keywork=&category=0&city=0&price=0&type=0`, so you'll need to figure out how to serve what you are supposed to serve given that URI.